# XCode 4.3.1 crashes on opening specific project

Tags: xcode, crash, project

Yesterday I updated my Xcode from 4.2.1 to 4.3.1 from Mac App Store. Everything was fine, but in the evening Xcode started to crash on opening one project, that I am currently working on. Here is the crash log here: http://pastebin.com/bxrMBeu7

I've also noticed that other projects are opening fine. Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've spent few hours to fix this. There is no need to reinstall xCode.

So, here is my solution:

1. Go to Organizer > Projects > Your project name. And delete Derived Data (not sure if this is necessary, but I did this few times before I've fixed)
2. Find you project (*.xcodeproj) in Finder and click 'Show Package Content'. Delete all user specific data from there (I did the same step removing folders with user specific data from svnX client Working Copy window).
3. Run the project.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I could start the Project and even Run it. Anyway xCode still crashing   on opening .xib file.