# xcode 4.5 crashes on opening project

Tags: xcode, crash

very annoying: xcode keeps crashing when I open one of my projects.

I have no clue why...

this one

[XCode 4.3.1 crashes on opening specific project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759209/xcode-4-3-1-crashes-on-opening-specific-project)

did not help - this is the crash log - any Ideas ?

```
Process:         Xcode [19761]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.5 (1839)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1839000000000000~3
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 10747437
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [198]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2012-10-01 21:48:52.265 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C54)
Report Version:  10
Sleep/Wake UUID: 9ACF0419-50CB-4C8A-9DAB-48BB96BC96BE

Interval Since Last Report:          92224 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           11
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  263627 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   11

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4G182
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-1877/Framework/Classes/Model/SourceControl/IDESourceControlUtilities.m:73
Details:  Unable to make tmp file
Function: DVTFilePath *IDESourceControl_filePathForTmpFileBasedOnFileName(NSString *)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40030a1e0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000101f63a5c -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010122a20d _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010122a2a5 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000101ad87b5 IDESourceControl_filePathForTmpFileBasedOnFileName (in IDEFoundation)
  4  0x00000001092a9c6e -[GitExportFileOperation initWithRequest:] (in IDEGit)
  5  0x000000010929e640 -[GitController operationForRequest:] (in IDEGit)
  6  0x0000000101a0c0d8 -[IDESourceControlManager performRequest:waitUntilFinished:withCompletionBlock:] (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x0000000101a91d99 __96-[IDESourceControlWorkingTreeGroup temporaryFolderForBranchName:revisionNumber:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEFoundation)
  8  0x0000000101a91c72 -[IDESourceControlWorkingTreeGroup temporaryFolderForBranchName:revisionNumber:completionBlock:] (in IDEFoundation)
  9  0x000000010201fd58 -[IDESourceControlWorkingTreeGroup(IDESourceControlDocumentLocationAdditions) exportPrivateTemporaryDocumentForBranchName:revisionName:usingTemplateDocument:completionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 10  0x0000000101eb8a18 -[IDEComparisonEditor _exportSecondaryDocument] (in IDEKit)
```

Comment: Seems like XCode has problems to create a temporary file somewhere on your system (Did you changed the project path?). Maybe something in the internal index of the project is damaged. As "first aid" i suggest to delete the derived data folder of the project you are try to open. Just go to "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/" and delete the folder which contain your project name. Also i would do a "git gc" and "git rm --cached" in you project folder for a a general clean up. As you can see the error happens somewhere in the source control of git hub. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the tip - unfortunately it did not help...